# NSLog with PlugIn development for Coda

Tags: objective-c, plugins, coda

I've just started and am attempting to write plug-ins for Coda.

Now, I can't for the life of me i can't figure out how or where NSLog's get outputted for debugging.  When the plugin is loaded by Coda, it works fine.  So my question is:

1) for the quick and dirty, should I be using NSLog w/ an app plugin?
2) what happens everytime I call NSLog from within a plugin while it's running from another app?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for it in `Console.app`, that's where you can look at most log files.

Plugins are normally loaded into the application's code and therefore have the same `stdout`. They print to the same file as the application does.